# Django reset password fail with PasswordResetView

Tags: django, passwords

I'm currently adding a way of reseting a user password for the website I develop. For that purpose, I used the built-in view of Django. You can find the relevant part of all the files below :

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('recuperation-mot-de-passe', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(email_template_name='inscription/reset_mail.html', subject_template_name='inscription/subject_mail.txt', success_url='recuperation-envoyee'), name = 'password-reset'),
    path('recuperation-envoyee', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password-reset-done'),
    path('recuperation-confirmee/<uidb64><token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url='recuperation-complete'), name = 'recuperation-confirmee'),
    path('recuperation-complete', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name = 'password-reset-complete'),
]
```

reset_mail.html

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}Vous recevez cet email car vous avez demandé à réinitialiser le mot de passe associé à votre compte Cook4Me.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Cliquer sur ce lien pour choisir un nouveau mot de passe :" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'recuperation-confirmee' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Votre identifiant, au cas où vous l'auriez oublié :" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Merci d'utiliser Cook4Me !" %}

{% blocktrans %}L'équipe Cook4Me{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

When I test all of this, the following problem happens : First, I enter my email address. The mail is correctly sent but I receive twice the same mail which I think is a first problem. The big problem is when I click on the reset link, I come to a page with the following error message : `"Password reset unsuccessful. The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset."`
I don't understand why I have this error since I use all the built-in views from Django. I guess the problem comes from the mail since I receive it twice (which isn't normal) and the error tells that the link was already used.
I've tried using the buit-in mail template of django and I get the same problem.

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : the double email problem came from the fact I add two users with the same email address in the database. This is now solved but I still have the same error as before with the reset link.

EDIT2 : I think I might have found the problem. It comes from the parameter in the url `recuperation-confirmee/<uidb64><token>`, I think I have to write it in another way but I can't find it, can someone help me ?

Comment: Fond a partial solution by myself, the url has to be written this way : ```recuperation-confirmee/<uidb64>/<token>``` This enables me to enter a new password, but after that, instead of by redirected to the success url, I get the same error as before. Can I have a little help this time please ?

Comment: instead of being*

Comment: SOLVED ! I add to remove the success url in the password_confirm template

Comment: Can you clarify what you did? Having the same problem